# JQuery Accordion th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

This should be any easy one for you. I want to have a table with rows that expand. I am trying to implement JQuery accordion on class="Accordion1".
it does not work at all.
What am I doing wrong?

```
...
<script>
$(function() {
$( "th.Accordion1").accordion();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="Accordion1">GROUP 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="Accordion1">GROUP 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>

        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the header option of jQuery Accordion.

```
$(function () {
    $('table').accordion({header: '.accordion1' });
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this post is quite old but I have two different solutions for the problem stated and thought to post them anyway, maybe someone is thankful for it.

You can find two options on my [Pen](https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/WEOVmO).

One including "Group 1" and "Group 2"...

```
<div class="options" id="op1">
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>GROUP 1</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Note</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h3>GROUP 2</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Note</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And one without

```
<div class="options" id="op2">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Be aware that for this to work you have to include jquery and jquery-ui!

The options I've added for the accordion and the CSS are optional... ;)